# SVG <use> with xlink.href not working with the fill url() attribute in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to apply styles to `<use>` element. I have an attribute `xlink.href` for shape and attribute `fill` with the `linearGradient`

The problem is that in Google Chrome this gradient is not displayed with the `<use>` tag, although in Microsoft Edge everything is fine, so we have a gradient filling for `<rect>` and `<use>` elements

Google Chrome:
[image: Url Fill chrome]

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <use 
        class="tooth-crown-main" 
        xlink:href="/assets/teeth/teeth.svg#b1-crown" 
        x="0" y="0" 
        fill="url(#ToothBackground)" 
        stroke="#a7a9ac" stroke-alignment="inner" stroke-width="0.3">
    </use>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="url(#ToothBackground)" />
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="ToothBackground"  gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#e3f3ef" />
            <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ffffff" />
            <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#ffffff" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e3f3ef" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Microsoft Edge:
[image: Url fill edge]

In Google Chrome earlier this worked fine, the same as in Microsoft Edge. Is it possible that the problem is related to the Chrome updates?

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!